# Couldn't load stored procedure through Silverlight and RIA

Tags: c#, silverlight, stored-procedures, domainservices, objectcontext

I want to dump the return into datagrid of silverlight application. I wrote a stored procedure with no key and just return 4 properties. I have imported the function into Entity Framework with

- Function Import Name :: LecAllInfo
- Stored procedure Name :: LecAllInfo
- Returns a Collection of :: Complex : LecAllInfo_Result
- Stored Procedure Column Information

  ```
  StartTime, EndTime, Venue, Purpose
  ```

Code in my Domain Service Class (OrganizationService.cs)

```
    public IQueryable<LecAllInfo_Result> LecAllInfoQuery(string lecId)
    {
        return this.ObjectContext.LecAllInfo(lecId).AsQueryable<LecAllInfo_Result>();
    }
```

Code in my Metadata (OrganizationService.metadata.cs)

```
[MetadataTypeAttribute(typeof(LecAllInfo_Result.LecAllInfo_ResultMetadata))]
public partial class LecAllInfo_Result
{
    internal sealed class LecAllInfo_ResultMetadata
     {
          private LecAllInfo_ResultMetadata()
          {
          }

          public DateTime StartTime { get; set; }
          public DateTime EndTime { get; set; }
          public string Venue { get; set; }
          public string Purpose { get; set; }
     }
}
```

But I failed to call back the LecAllInfo in usual way, which is ::

```
var context = new OrganizationContext();
context.Load(context.GetLecNotificationQuery(((App) Application.Current).GloUid), loadLectNort, null);
context.Load(context.Lec << Unable to Load it
```

> context.Load(context.LecAllInfo("LP123112"), true);
>
> will return error and resharper telling
>   me to create method in 'OrganizationContext.LecAllInfo'

May I know is there something wrong with my structure of code or how can i edit this while i got no idea on how to make it ??

when i click the resharper option, it created this at SolutionName.Web.g.cs

```
    public EntityQuery<object> LecAllInfo(string lp123112)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }
```

I followed several tutorial available on web, stackoverflow members post as well but still failed to do so. Thank you for reply

Comment: @marc_s, do you know where is the problem to cause this failure in calling the query from client ??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To load Store Procedure should define anything as key in return. SOLVED